# Is this first order theory equal to the complete theory of real numbers?

Tags: first-order-logic, real-numbers

Let our language $L$ be $\{+,-,*,0,1,\leq \}$. In that language, suppose we have the axioms for ordered fields, and also an axiom schema stating that every parameter-free definable set that is nonempty and bounded above has a supremum. Is that theory the complete theory of the real numbers? I actually asked this question [several years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531177/is-this-an-axiomatization-of-real-closed-fields), but there was a misinterpretation, where people thought I meant "definable with parameters". So, now, I am including this clarification that I mean definable without parameters.

Edit: Also, if this theory is not the complete theory of real numbers, can someone exhibit a model of this theory that is not elementarily equivalent to the ordered field of real numbers?

Comment: I think it is not, and that $\mathbb{A}(r)$, where $\mathbb{A}$ is the field of algebraic real numbers and $r$ is transcendental, will demonstrate this: clearly $r$ does not have a square root in this ordered field, but I believe it does satisfy your theory. However, I don't at the moment see an argument for this.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If $r$ doesn't have a square root, the bounded-above set $\{x\in\Bbb A(r):x^2<r\}$ wouldn't have supremum.

Comment: @Berci In the OP there's a restriction to *parameter-freely* definable sets, which that isn't since it uses the parameter $r$. (Namely: "... an axiom schema stating that every **parameter-free** definable set that is nonempty and bounded above has a supremum" - emphasis mine.)

Comment: Indeed, that's true.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Presumably some transcendental numbers are expressible through parameter-free formulas, and so they need to be in the field, as do their square roots, etc.... for instance, can't you say that $e$ is the supremum of $(1+1/n)^n$ over $n \ge 1$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Nope, since exponentiation isn't part of the language. In fact, the definable elements of the field of real numbers are exactly the algebraic reals.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: You're right.... that occurred to me after posting.  Then why do you need $\mathbb{A}(r)$ at all?  Doesn't $\mathbb{A}$ itself work as a counterexample?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Because $\mathbb{A}$ **is** elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer That is not what I meant. I meant to consider $\mathbb{A}(r)$ for some *specific* transcendental real $r$; say, $\mathbb{A}(\pi)$. The ordering is the restriction of the usual one on all of $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, it's Archimedean.

Comment: This question has been answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383259/is-this-theory-the-complete-theory-of-the-real-ordered-field/385222#385222), both with an explicit example and a forcing construction. See also my comment to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/383297/2126), which I think shows that the example of $\mathbb{A}(r)$ does not work. @NoahSchweber